# How take all elements from IList<object> with [0] index LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets

I have 3 columns in google table, and I fill them out and want to exclude duplicate emails.

How to select all values from `IList<object>` with 0 index (has [0],[1],[2] indexes, i need only [0] index).
row[0].ToString() take 1 email from google sheets and checks it. but this method make to much requests to google api and i dont know how take all value with 1 request

```cs
IList<IList<object>> values = response.Values;
if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
{   
    foreach (var row in values)
    {
        if (String.Equals(row[0].ToString(), email.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

The way to take the first object of a enumeration with LINQ is to use [`.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8) or [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8). If you want the whole code above in linq it would look like

```
var trimmedEmail = email.Trim();
var result = !values.Any(
v => String.Equals(row.First().ToString(), trimmedEmail , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

**Edit:** should be *any()*, not *all()*

I.e. If all the values in the first column equals trimmedEmail, result=true, otherwise result=false.

This will probably not help with your performance problems since `first()` it is conceptually equivalent to `row[0]`. This however depend entirely on the implementation of the IList you are using. Since you mention the google API I would assume that this is not a regular `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

If your problem is the number of web-calls then I would suggest posting a new question that asks specifically on how to reduce the number of web-calls, and include the API used and the specific calls you are making.

Comment: This is the same variant as mine?
it does not select all values by 0 index,how I understand this code, it will only work in a loop. am i right? all needed values already have in "values" and can be get without a loop in linq

Comment: `Any` checks checks if the _Any_ of the inner lists have the first element equal to the trimmed email. So what he wrote is equivalent to your question or do you want to select all the inner values?